# Aligning three divs side by side and along the bottom of the longest

Tags: html, css

I know similar questions have been asked, but my scenario is slightly different. I have three divs, which are aligned in a row. I basically want all of their content to be pushed to the bottom. I've tried using position: relative and position: absolute, bottom: 0, but that didn't work.

Here is the css and some images. I put borders to try to clarify:

```
.topAlbums {
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.album0 {
    width: 33%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    padding-bottom: 500em;
    margin-bottom: -500em;
}
.album1 {
    width: 33%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    padding-bottom: 500em;
    margin-bottom: -500em;
}
.album2 {
    width: 33%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    padding-bottom: 500em;
    margin-bottom: -500em;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Put the internal content in a div container and assign position relative to it and then bottom :0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use display values as table, table-row and table-cell with which you can create the same heights as well as the vertical align to the bottom.

Check the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/oyzorx4r/

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      info in it at the bottom
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      some more info<br /><Br /> with extra breaks
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <p>
        lots of info<br /><br /><Br /><Br /><br />and some more
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.table {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.row {
  display:table-row;
}
.cell {
  display:table-cell;
  width:33%;
  background:red;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```